# PJSIP Android Call cannot hear while having other VOIP call?

Tags: android, audio, sip, pjsip

we are using psjip in Android. We are having an issue regarding Audio doesn't work when there is another VOIP call going on.
Steps to reproduce

*- Start Microsoft Team Call on 2 android phones.

- Start PJSIP voip call in Android.
- You cannot hear the other person, also you cannot speak. The other person cannot hear you.
- You end the Team Call.
- You can now speak and hear the other person.*

**Problem 1:** We should be able to hear each other on our pjsip voip call. If you bring the app foreground.
**Problem 2:** After ending Microsoft Team call. The speaker switches to rear piece mode. And Im unable to switch it back to speaker. Problem 2 is really weird.

Without parallel to other VOIP calls, our app works fine.

Using the below code for speaker switching

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Comment: about problem #1: maybe check audio focus, about problem #2: got same [some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70768622/audiomanager-auto-switching-own-mode-not-respecting-setspeakerphoneon)

Comment: @snachmsm can you provide some reference about the audio focus?

Comment: search for "android audio focus", e.g. [THIS article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/audio-focus-1-6b32689e4380) popped up. just a suspection

Comment: @snachmsm While in team meeting, I requested a focus in my app and dial and outgoing call. I can see this message AudioFocus: REQUEST_GRANTED. But still, I cannot talk to another person. The moment the call is ended on Team, I can see this message AudioFocus: AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN. And now I can talk now. Isn't there a way to forcefully request a focus, as Microsoft Team manages to retain the focus every time.